# How to set a state in a forEach loop using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to transfer data in an array A into a object B, so i doing something like [array].forEach(e => setB({...B, e})), but it seems like when traversing on later elements, former actions have been "forgotten", how should i achieve my goal?
Prototype should looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {Map} from "immutable"

export default function App() {
    const [arrayA, setA] = React.useState([1, 2]);
    const [objB, setB] = React.useState(Map({}));
    React.useEffect(() => {
        arrayA.forEach(num => {
            setB(objB.set(num, num*num));
        })
    }, [])

    return (<div>null</div>)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `stale data` and you should use `setState callback` like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [arrayA, setA] = React.useState([1, 2]);
  const [objB, setB] = React.useState(Map({}));
  React.useEffect(() => {
    arrayA.forEach((num) => {
      setB(oldValue => oldValue.set(num, num * num));
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>null</div>;
}
```

Comment: Considering the actual operation for each loop is a fetch operation, and the setter was triggerd inside the fetch.then function, so it seems it's the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. With a regular value state update in a loop each subsequent enqueued update overwrites the previous update, so the last update is the one used for the next render cycle.

## Solution

Normally you would use a functional state update to update from the previous state, not the state from the previous render cycle. In this case it makes more sense to map the `arrayA` state to an array of key-value pairs and do a single update for the `objB` state.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setB(Map(arrayA.map(num => [num, num * num]));
}, []);
```